# Emails embedded withing Emails saving to Salesforce

Tags: email, embedded

In Salesforce Enterprise Edition a user Sent and Added an Email to Salesforce from Outlook.  The Email had another email embedded in it.  The user cannot find the parent email in the Activity History but can find the embedded email.  Has anyone else noticed this happening?